# AC_CHECK_LIB in multiple places

Tags: oracle, autoconf

Some Oracle client installations provide both 32-bit and 64-bit shared libraries, for example:

- `$ORACLE_HOME/lib`
- `$ORACLE_HOME/lib32`

How do I find with `autoconf` the correct location of libclntsh for current target architecture?

`AC_CHECK_PROG` family has optional `[path = ‘$PATH’]` parameter. `AC_CHECK_LIB` has none.

Tried in a loop:

```
saveLIBS=$LIBS

for my_archdir in baddir lib32 lib; do
  LIBS="$saveLIBS -L$ORACLE_HOME/$my_archdir"
  AC_CHECK_LIB([clntsh],[sqlcxt])
done
```

results:

```
checking for sqlcxt in -lclntsh... no
checking for sqlcxt in -lclntsh... (cached) no
checking for sqlcxt in -lclntsh... (cached) no
```

Looks like `AC_CHECK_LIB` cannot be called twice. It always returns the first cached result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache variable name is documented. Now I unset it before next iteration:

```
# check $ORACLE_HOME/lib
saveLIBS=$LIBS

# break after 1st try, if was cached; reset if it wasn't
if ${ac_cv_lib_clntsh_sqlcxt+:} false; then :
  my_cont='break'
else
  my_cont='unset ac_cv_lib_clntsh_sqlcxt'
fi

for my_archdir in lib lib32 lib64; do
  LIBS="$saveLIBS -L$ORACLE_HOME/$my_archdir"
  AC_CHECK_LIB([clntsh],[sqlcxt])
  test "x$ac_cv_lib_clntsh_sqlcxt" != "xyes" || break # break if found
  $my_cont
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.  I use `AC_CHECK_LIB` to determine if libdvbpsi is available.

At first, I used the following:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([dvbpsi], [dvbpsi_pat_attach])
```

But then I realized that `dvbpsi_pat_attach` is a function name that is present only in the latest builds.  Older versions of the library use an older naming convention and the function is named `dvbpsi_AttachPAT`.  My own project has backwards compatibility support for both old and new builds of the library, so I should be able to detect both.  The following is what I use now:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB([dvbpsi], [dvbpsi_pat_attach], [], [AC_CHECK_LIB([dvbpsi], [dvbpsi_AttachPAT])])
```

The first two parameters are the same as what you're used to.  The third parameter is left empty.  This parameter is the `action if found` , which we want nothing.  The next parameter is the `action if not found` ... If not found, we want to repeat the test but search for a different function name.  I've inserted a nested `AC_CHECK_LIB` in the `action if not found` case and now this block detects both old and new versions of the library correctly.

Obviously, this is not a direct solution to your problem, but it addresses the fact that "AC_CHECK_LIB cannot be called twice. It always returns the first cached result.", as you have described in your question.

In your case, you can try the following code block:

```
LIBS="$saveLIBS -L$ORACLE_HOME/baddir"
AC_CHECK_LIB([clntsh], [sqlcxt], [], [
  LIBS="$saveLIBS -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib32"
  AC_CHECK_LIB([clntsh], [sqlcxt], [], [
    LIBS="$saveLIBS -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib"
    AC_CHECK_LIB([clntsh], [sqlcxt])
  ])
])
```

Comment: Nested checks often produce invalid configure script: e.g a shell function defined after it is called

Comment: it's safe in this case.  works quite well in my own project:  https://github.com/mkrufky/libdvbtee/blob/master/configure.ac (line 47)